# How to print x amount of answer instead of printing x amount of value?

Tags: python

I found this code on stackoverflow and everything works but I want to change the way it is printed. In this code, it prints everything where the value(n) is prime and up to 100. What I want to do is print the first hundred prime numbers. How do I do this? I have tried some kind of "(primes * 100)" because I thought multiplying it might work but it didn't. Thank you in advance.

```py
def primes(n):
        primeslist = [2]
        for i in range (2,n):
            p = 1
            for j in primeslist:

                if (i%j) == 0:
                    p = 0
                    break
            if p == 1:
                primeslist.append(i)
        return primeslist

primeslist = primes(100)
print(primeslist)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code please?

Comment: This is the full code.

Answer (score 2):

You can print a slice of your list:

```
print(primeslist[:100])
```

If you want them in seperate lines:

```
print("\n".join([str(i) for i in primeslist[:100]]))
```

If you want to PRODUCE first 100 primes instead of primes up to value of 100 you must change:

```
for i in range (2,n):
```

to

```
while len(primeslist)<100:
```

Comment: Don't forget to manually increment `i` when using the `while` loop.

Comment: What does it mean to manually increment? I am in my third week of learning python and things are going pretty slow hahah.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print first n number of primes, this is one way of doing it.

```
i = 1
while True:
    i += 1
    p = 1
    for j in primeslist:

        if (i%j) == 0:
            p = 0
            break
    if p == 1:
        primeslist.append(i)
    if len(primeslist) == n:
        return primeslist
```

or this is another way of doing.

```
i = 1
while len(primeslist) == n:
    i += 1
    p = 1
    for j in primeslist:

        if (i%j) == 0:
            p = 0
            break
    if p == 1:
        primeslist.append(i)
   
return primeslist
```